# Remove annoing element (<div>) resizing when showing <input>

Tags: html, css, input, font-family

As you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jW2re/9/) JSFiddle, when you change the radio button the button's div and the bottom div move themself.
This is due to the font of the radios and the date input, because with "normal" font doesn't happen, but it is also very annoing. How can I solve the problem?

HTML here, CSS and JS in JSFiddle

```
<div id="cont" class="write">      
    <div>
        <div>TEXT</div>
        <div>some text some text some text some text some text </div>
    </div>

    <div>
         <input type="radio"
                name="att"
                id="on"
                value="on"
                onclick="showFrom(this)"
         />
         <label for="on">On</label>

         <input type="radio"
                name="att"
                id="on_f"
                value="on_f"
                onclick="showFrom(this)"
                checked="checked"
         />
         <label for="on_f">From:</label>

         <input type="date"
                id="on_f_d"
                name="on_f_d"
                disabled="disabled"
                placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"
        />
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>TEXT</div>
        <div>some text some text some text some text some text </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the issue is. I'm not seeing any font changes or box moves... Firefox/Mac

Comment: Mac doesn't support Segoe, neither Firefox: this is because you don't have the problem

Comment: If the font is changing the size of the element, then you need set a fixed width/height so that they don't expand and affect areas around.